# Output GCD of n numbers

Tags: kotlin, math

Using euclidean algorithm find GCD of N numbers

[image]

```
fun main(){
    var n = 3
    var m = IntArray(n)
    m.set(0, 24)
    m.set(1, 18)
    m.set(2, 30)
    var ex29 = Ex29()
    ex29.GCD(m)
}
class Ex29 {
    fun GCD(array: IntArray){
        if (array.toSet().size==1){
            println(array[0])
        }
        var array2 = array
        while (array2.toSet().size!=1){
            array2.sort()
            var new_array=IntArray(50)
             new_array[0]=array[0]
            var dif:Int
            for(i in 0 until array2.size-1){
                dif = array2[i+1]-array2[i]
                if(dif>0){
                    new_array.set(i+1, dif)
                }
            }
            array2=new_array
        }
        println(array2[0])
    }
}
```

No error but wants me to type something in the console. Even though I infinitely type, it never stops.

Answer (score 0):

You've got yourself stuck in an infinite loop and you need to try and debug what's going on.

I suggest adding some statements to log variables at useful points in the code, and limiting the iterations of the `while` loop so the program can terminate and show you the log output.

Following that approach, I've tweaked your code as follows ([playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)):

```
fun main(){
    var n = 3
    var m = IntArray(n)
    m.set(0, 24)
    m.set(1, 18)
    m.set(2, 30)
    var ex29 = Ex29()
    ex29.GCD(m)
}
class Ex29 {
    fun GCD(array: IntArray){
        if (array.toSet().size==1){
            println(array[0])
        }
        var array2 = array
        // removing while loop for now...
        // while (array2.toSet().size!=1){
        for (j in 1..20) { // Adding a finite loop...
            println("At loop number $j") // ... logging the loop number...
            array2.log() // ... and the array at that point.
            array2.sort()
            var new_array=IntArray(50)
             new_array[0]=array[0]
            var dif:Int
            for(i in 0 until array2.size-1){
                dif = array2[i+1]-array2[i]
                if(dif>0){
                    new_array.set(i+1, dif)
                }
            }
            array2=new_array
        }
        println(array2[0])
    }
}

// A new convenience function for logging an array
fun IntArray.log() {
    val arrayString = this.joinToString(", ")
    println("Array of length ${this.size} logged: $arrayString")
}
```

Now you can try and run that and figure out where your program is going wrong.